# Keep active virtualenv on new tab

Tags: virtualenv, zsh, virtualenvwrapper

I use gnome-terminal with zsh. I recently had an issue with keeping the current working directory when opening a new tab (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) since it used to reset itself to `$HOME` everytime. I solved it by adding:

```
. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

to the `.zshrc` file.

Now, since I use virtualenv (and virtualenvwrapper) I would like to avoid having to do `workon virtualenv_name` each time I open a new tab.

The obvious solution is to put that command in the `.zshrc`, however I don't want to *always* enter the virtualenv. I want to do it only when I open a new tab and I am already inside a virtualenv.

Now, since a virtualenv is just a modification to `PATH`, `PS1`, and stuff like that, I guess I can do this in some way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the auto export solutions, e.g. https://direnv.net or https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv. These solutions can be used to turn on a virtual env when cding into its directory.